# how to use vaultQuery in Corda

Tags: corda

In Corda HelloWorld example following state is defined:

```
class IOUState(val value: Int,
           val lender: Party,
           val borrower: Party) : ContractState {
override val participants get() = listOf(lender, borrower)
}
```

To query for IOUState in the vault using RPC, I want to use the following API:

```
vaultQuery(contractStateType: Class<out t>)  Vault.Page<T>
```

what parameter should be passed to vaultQuery?

Tried using the following:

```
vaultQuery(IOUState)
```

but following is reported:

```
“Classifier “IOUState” does not  have a companion object and 
 thus must be initialized here”
```

Using following does not work either

```
(IOUState(0, null, null))
```

What parameter should be passed that is of type:

```
Class<out IOUState)
```

The following worked:
     vaultQuery(IOUState::class.java)

Answer (score 1):

vaultQuery(BillState::class.java)